# Multiple map implementation in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I used multiple marker map in my website , I added all static data its coming fine ,I want to convert sttaic to dynamic as per my db .

```html
var features = [
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.820553,30.802498000000014),
    }, 
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(24.770300473681075,46.384158004687485),
    }, 
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(26.820553,30.802498000000014),
    }, 
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(21.788924411377383,57.10016540039055),
    }, 
    {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(20.593684,78.96288000000004),
    }
];
```

I am getting location array using foreach like this , how can i implemets with above map code ,

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => xyz
        [lat] => 24.7970581
        [lng] =>  46.7004561
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => xyz
        [lat] => 24.7970581
        [lng] =>  46.7004561
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode the array into json in php and loop through it in js

```
var json = <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>; //$arr your array


var data = [];

    for(var i of json){

       data.push({
        position: [i.lat,i.lng]
       })

    }

    console.log(data);
```